# Angular import external javascript file, getting no exported member and compile errors

Tags: javascript, angular, charts

I am writing an angular component and got a open source module working with npm install. Now I made some some changes and want to import the javascript file  like so

```
import { ModuleName } from './../../ModuleFolder/ModuleName';
```

When I place the cursor above the *ModuleName* inside the bracket, I see the highlighted red error saying *Module* has not export member '`ModuleName`';

In my ts code, I have referenced the Module like so

object: `ModuleName`; which is also complaining.

I google and the post says using npm install but I don't want to add this module to my node_module list. I am moving the folder out to make my customization.

I also tried the following but it is not working

```
import   './../../ModuleName.bundle.min.js';
```

I am wondering does the name of the *Module* needs to be registered somewhere to be able to reference it in my component?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you show the code of your `Module`?

Comment: You need to let typescript know where the module is located, which is in your tsconfig

Comment: is there an example to add the module to tsconfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'declare' after the import statements

```
declare const _moduleName;
```

**For example:**
 I am using  [Swiper.js](http://idangero.us/swiper/get-started/) library using cdn. In my angular component, I refer it using a ***declare*** keyword.

```
declare const Swiper;

var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', { /* ... */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

I got external libraries working in Angular by following the following links

https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-javascript-libraries-in-angular-2-apps-ff274ba601af